# FullPage.js not scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm working on this site http://www.lodahl.aero/ which is using fullpage.js for the front page.  Although it was working fine at one point, it's stopped now and (I'm sure its something silly) but i cannot figure out why.  Basically you cannot scroll up or down with the mouse wheel or pageup/pagedown keys to or from the first slide.  You can flip between the 2nd and 3rd slide fine, but the 1st one is not playing ball.  Can anyone elighten me as to what I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle of your code, so we can actually take a look thanks

Comment: It works ok for  me.